# Json aggregation of data with missing values

Tags: sql, json, postgresql, psql, jsonb

I have a simple table of supplements

```
create table consumption (
    account bigint not null,
    date date not null,
    supplement text not null check (supplement in ('multiVitamin', 'calMag', 'omega3', 'potassium', 'salt', 'antiOxidant', 'enzymes')),
    quantity integer not null default 0
);
```

And I want to fetch what people have consumed per day. This would be an exmaple of my desired output

```
[
    {
        "date" : "2016-01-01",
        "multiVitamin" : 7,
        "calMag" : 0,
        "omega3" : 3,
        "potassium" : 3,
        "salt" : 2,
        "antiOxidant" : 0,
        "enzymes" : 1
    },
    {
        "date" : "2016-01-02",
        "multiVitamin" : 2,
        "calMag" : 1,
        "omega3" : 1,
        "potassium" : 2,
        "salt" : 2,
        "antiOxidant" : 0,
        "enzymes" : 1
    }
]
```

I'm confused how to get those values into a json object and coalesce so that I return 0 if there aren't any supplements entered for that day. So everyday should return all supplements. This is what I have so far but its very far from complete - it's at least fetching for the dates selected though.

```
WITH duration_amount AS (
SELECT date_trunc('day', date)::date AS date_group,     json_build_object('quantity', SUM(consumption.quantity) )::jsonb->'quantity' as supplement
FROM consumption
WHERE account = 1667
GROUP BY date_group
)
SELECT DISTINCT date_group, supplement
FROM (
SELECT generate_series(date_trunc('day', '2016-10-20'::date), '2016-10-28'::date, '1 day') AS date_group
) x
LEFT JOIN duration_amount
USING (date_group)
ORDER BY date_group DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

Example data:

```
insert into consumption values
(1667, '2016-10-21', 'multiVitamin', 1),
(1667, '2016-10-21', 'calMag', 2),
(1667, '2016-10-22', 'multiVitamin', 3),
(1667, '2016-10-22', 'calMag', 4),
(1667, '2016-10-22', 'omega3', 5);
```

You should prepare a template table containing rows for all possible values. In the example it will contain 14 rows (cross join 2 days with 7 supplements). Next, left join to it your table using `coalesce()` for missing values:

```
select 
    date_group::date as date, 
    supplement_group as supplement, 
    coalesce(quantity, 0) quantity
from generate_series('2016-10-21'::date, '2016-10-22', '1 day') as date_group
cross join (
    values 
        ('multiVitamin'), ('calMag'), ('omega3'), 
        ('potassium'), ('salt'), ('antiOxidant'), ('enzymes') 
    ) as supplements(supplement_group)
left join consumption 
    on date_group = date 
    and supplement = supplement_group 
    and account = 1667;

    date    |  supplement  | quantity 
------------+--------------+----------
 2016-10-21 | multiVitamin |        1
 2016-10-21 | calMag       |        2
 2016-10-21 | omega3       |        0
 2016-10-21 | potassium    |        0
 2016-10-21 | salt         |        0
 2016-10-21 | antiOxidant  |        0
 2016-10-21 | enzymes      |        0
 2016-10-22 | multiVitamin |        3
 2016-10-22 | calMag       |        4
 2016-10-22 | omega3       |        5
 2016-10-22 | potassium    |        0
 2016-10-22 | salt         |        0
 2016-10-22 | antiOxidant  |        0
 2016-10-22 | enzymes      |        0
(14 rows)
```

The result can be easily aggregated to `jsonb`, [see the full example here.](http://rextester.com/GOCRA45617)

Comment: Oh man. That is amazing. Thanks so much. This is exactly what I was looking for. I had never seen the cross join before.